# Using NbClust for Number of clusters in gene expression data does not work

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a normalized gene expression data, with 2800 rows and 600 columns. I need to find the number of clusters, I am trying to use `NbClust` function to calculate the number of clusters using different methods and to use majority rule to choose the number which occurs the most. But I get the following error:

`library(NbClust)
nb <- NbClust(ranked.expr, distance = NULL, min.nc = 2,
        max.nc = 10, method = "complete", index ="all")`

But I am getting the error:

`Error in NbClust(ranked.exprs[1:2825, 1:598], distance = NULL, min.nc = 2,  : 
  The TSS matrix is indefinite. There must be too many missing values. The index cannot be calculated.`

Any hints what could be the reason and how can I make it to work?

Comment: `NbClust` gives a false impression of finding the best result.  Best score on some indexes does not only optimal results in practice.

Comment: What is then the best way to find the optimal result?

Comment: The one that *works* best, not the one that has a pretty score on a measure completely unrelated to your real problem.

Comment: The problem is that I am using different approaches and getting different numbers, but how I I know which one is correct?

Comment: What is "correct"? Can you write down a mathematical equation that measures "correctness"? None is correct, because there is no "correct". Every result or parameter is only a guess. Study the results to learn about your data, but do not assume there would be a "correct" result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict the indexes since some of them don't work (they cannot compute on your data). Through trials and errors you can get a working list of `index` values (see the [documentation of NbClust](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NbClust/versions/3.0/topics/NbClust) for possible values of `index`).